# Does my loss custom function do what I think it does?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model with a custom loss function (shown below). The expected behavior is, when the first digit (of the 4th rank) of the ground truth is positive, the network should try to approximate all 8 parameters. Otherwise, it should just try to approximate only the first parameter (and just output whatever for the others). In other words, when the first parameter of the true set is 0 or negative, the rest of the params shouldn't matter. Did I do it right? Can I use a tf slice thing like this?

I'm noticing that parameters 1-7 are universally closer to 0 than I'd expect. As if the function was just doing MSE everywhere.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    truthiness = tf.greater(y_true[:, :, :, 0], tf.constant(0.0))

    loss = tf.where(
        truthiness,
        tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true[:, :, :, 0:8], y_pred[:, :, :, 0:8]),
        tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true[:, :, :, 0], y_pred[:, :, :, 0]),
    )

    return loss
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be some unexpected (at least to me) behavior in Keras.losses.MeanSquaredError. I ended up just implementing my loss in plain tensorflow.

```
truthiness = tf.cast(tf.greater(y_true[:, :, :, 0], tf.constant(0.0)), dtype=tf.float32)
falsyness = tf.cast(tf.less_equal(y_true[:, :, :, 0], tf.constant(0.0)), dtype=tf.float32)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true[:, :, :, 0] - y_pred[:, :, :, 0])) + \
        tf.multiply(
           truthiness,
           tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true[:, :, :, 1:8] - y_pred[:, :, :, 1:8])),
        )

loss_2 = tf.multiply(truthiness, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true[:, :, :, 0:8], y_pred[:, :, :, 0:8])) + \
        tf.multiply(falsyness, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_true[:, :, :, 0], y_pred[:, :, :, 0]))
```

I'd expect loss and loss_2 to be equivalent, but they aren't. Re-inventing the wheel FTW!